# Python function to take text file and create dictionary with keys as words and values as frequencies

Tags: python, dictionary

first off I apologize in advance if anything is hard to understand in my question as I am a beginner in python and quite tired as it is late.

I am trying to figure out why I keep receiving errors while creating this function to take a text file and create a dictionary which contains the words as well as the frequencies and also prints which word has the highest frequency in the file.

Here is my code:

```
def poet(filename):
    word_frequency = {}
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.replace('.',"")
                word = word.replace(',',"")
                word = word.replace(';',"")
                if word in word_frequency:
                    word_frequency[word] += 1;
                else:
                    word_frequency[word] = 1;
most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
print("The word " + most_freq_word + " is in text ")
str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times"
print(word_frequency)


poet('Poem.txt')
```

And here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Noah/Desktop/Python/3.py", line 20, in <module>
    str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times"
NameError: name 'word_frequency' is not defined
```

Also, if anything is unclear please comment and I will respond right away, thank you in advance.

Edit:

Thank you for the responses, I have implemented this into my code but I am now receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Noah/Desktop/Python/3.py", line 20, in <module>
    poet('FrostPoem.txt')
  File "C:/Users/Noah/Desktop/Python/3.py", line 14, in poet
    most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

The new code is:

```
def poet(filename):
    word_frequency = {}
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.replace('.',"")
                word = word.replace(',',"")
                word = word.replace(';',"")
                if word in word_frequency:
                    word_frequency[word] += 1;
                else:
                    word_frequency[word] = 1;

    most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
    print("The word " + most_freq_word + " is in text " + \
    str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times")
    print(word_frequency)


poet('Poem.txt')
```

Comment: <s>The line that that error is on does not seem to be in the code you've  given.</s> Ah, formatting issue.

Comment: Yes my apologies, fixed it now.

Comment: The indentation also looks like it's messed up (probably Stack Overflow's fault). Can you fix it so it looks the same as your code?

Comment: Yes I didn't notice that thank you, it is now formatted exactly like my code.

Comment: You are complicating things way too much :/

Answer (score 1):

Ah-ha, there's your problem: several of your lines should be *inside* the function, like so:

```
def poet(filename):
    word_frequency = {}
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.replace('.',"")
                word = word.replace(',',"")
                word = word.replace(';',"")
                if word in word_frequency:
                    word_frequency[word] += 1;
                else:
                    word_frequency[word] = 1;

    most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
    print("The word " + most_freq_word + " is in text " + \
    str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times")
    print(word_frequency)


poet('Poem.txt')
```

Now, you might want this function to be more reusable, like if you didn't want to print immediately but wanted to do something further with `word_frequency`. In that case, you would need a `return` statement and your code might look like this:

```
def poet(filename):
    word_frequency = {}
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.replace('.',"")
                word = word.replace(',',"")
                word = word.replace(';',"")
                if word in word_frequency:
                    word_frequency[word] += 1;
                else:
                    word_frequency[word] = 1;

    return word_frequency

word_freq = poet('Poem.txt')
most_freq_word = max(word_freq, key=word_freq)
print("The word " + most_freq_word + " is in text " + \
str(word_freq[most_freq_word]) + " times")
print(word_freq)
```

---

In response to your edit, replace this line

```
    most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
```

with this line

```
    most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=lambda x:word_frequency[x])
```

This gets the maximum based on the values of the keys.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have implemented your input into my code, but I am now receiving a different error, I have edited the question including it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times"` in python, it suppose that `word_frequency` was declared before.In you case `word_frequency`is declared in `poet` function.

Check if there is an indentation problem.

You need dictionary keys.
To solve it, use `key=word_frequency.get`

Answer (score 0):

You define `word_frequency` inside the function `poet()`, so the scope is local, but you use the dictionary outside, and this gives the error.

```
def poet(filename):
    word_frequency = {}
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            word = word.replace('.',"")
            word = word.replace(',',"")
            word = word.replace(';',"")
            if word in word_frequency:
                word_frequency[word] += 1;
            else:
                word_frequency[word] = 1;
    most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
    print("The word " + most_freq_word + " is in text ")
    str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times"
    print(word_frequency)

poet('Poem.txt')
```

Put all the instruction inside the function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

def poet(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        counter = Counter(f.read().split())
    return counter
```

In case you want to strip ',' or ';' for example just stript it before or map over the list to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

`word_frequency` is only defined in the scope of `poet` function.
To access it outside of the function you should return it

```
word_frequency = poet('Poem.txt')
most_freq_word = max(word_frequency, key=word_frequency)
print("The word " + most_freq_word + " is in text ")
str(word_frequency[most_freq_word]) + " times"
print(word_frequency)
```

Also there are better solutions for your problem. You can check the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#counter-objects). The example does exactly what you want